# How can I send interactive messages in WhatsApp Bot using DialogFlow or NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, whatsapp

[image]

Hello I'm trying to send new message through whatsapp bot developed by dialogflow, 360dialog for the API and NodeJS

This is the payload that I'm trying to use:

```
{
  "type": "list",
  "header": {
    "type": "text",
    "text": "your-header-content"
  },
  "body": {
    "text": "your-text-message-content"
  },
  "footer": {
    "text": "your-footer-content"
  },
  "action": {
      "buttons": [
        {
          "type": "reply",
          "reply": {
            "id": "unique-postback-id",
            "title": "First Button’s Title" 
          }
        }
        
      ] 
    }
}
```